# Bootstrap tabs - multiple cards on the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get multiple cards to show up beside each other under Bootstrap 4 tabs. I can get the cards to work fine without the tabs but when I add the tabs, the cards are only 1 per line (no matter the width).

This code shows the cards outside and inside the tabs (outside works, inside does not). Any ideas?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Tracking DB</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid'>

    <div class='col-md-5'>
      <div class='row module-row'>

        <div class='col-md-4'>
          <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
              <div class=''>Weight</div>
            </div>
            <div class='card-body module-card-body'>
              <div>Weight Start: 215 lbs</div>
              <div>Weight Current: 213 lbs</div>
              <div>Weight Average: 285.7 lbs</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-4'>
          <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
              <div class=''>Fitness</div>
            </div>
            <div class='card-body module-card-body'>100 burpee Wednesday - 511 (8)<br>2 minute burpees - 711 (25)</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class='row'>

        <nav>
          <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-first-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-first" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-first" aria-selected="true">First</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-second" aria-selected="false">Second</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-third-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-third" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-third" aria-selected="false">Third</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-first-tab">
            <div class='col-md-4'>
              <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
                  <div class=''>Weight</div>
                </div>
                <div class='card-body module-card-body'>
                  <div>Weight Start: 215 lbs</div>
                  <div>Weight Current: 213 lbs</div>
                  <div>Weight Average: 285.7 lbs</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-4'>
              <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
                  <div class=''>Fitness</div>
                </div>
                <div class='card-body module-card-body'>100 burpee Wednesday - 511 (8)<br>2 minute burpees - 711</div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-second-tab">
            This is the content on the second tab
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-third" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-third-tab">
            Nothing on the third tab
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has everything to do with your nesting of elements. When you use bootstrap grid, you are constantly defining rows that are divided into columns. If you keep nesting rows in columns in rows, you will create ever more narrow columns. You're constantly subdividing the available space.

Also, I would recommend making sure that `.row` directly wraps `.col` divs. Your ends result will be much more predictable.

I added some `html` comments within the snippet.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Tracking DB</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid'>

    <div class='col-md-5'>
      <div class='row module-row'>

        <div class='col-md-4'>
          <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
              <div class=''>Weight</div>
            </div>
            <div class='card-body module-card-body'>
              <div>Weight Start: 215 lbs</div>
              <div>Weight Current: 213 lbs</div>
              <div>Weight Average: 285.7 lbs</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-4'>
          <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
              <div class=''>Fitness</div>
            </div>
            <div class='card-body module-card-body'>100 burpee Wednesday - 511 (8)<br>2 minute burpees - 711 (25)</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class='row'>

        <nav>
          <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-first-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-first" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-first" aria-selected="true">First</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-second" aria-selected="false">Second</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-third-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-third" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-third" aria-selected="false">Third</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-first-tab">
          <div class='row'><!-- I moved this row to directly wrap the children columns -->
            <div class='col-md-6 col-xs-6'><!-- also, adjsuted the specified width -->
              <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
                  <div class=''>Weight</div>
                </div>
                <div class='card-body module-card-body'>
                  <div>Weight Start: 215 lbs</div>
                  <div>Weight Current: 213 lbs</div>
                  <div>Weight Average: 285.7 lbs</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-6 col-xs-6'>
              <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-header module-card-header bg-secondary text-light'>
                  <div class=''>Fitness</div>
                </div>
                <div class='card-body module-card-body'>100 burpee Wednesday - 511 (8)<br>2 minute burpees - 711</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-second-tab">
          This is the content on the second tab
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-third" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-third-tab">
          Nothing on the third tab
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```